# Shannon entropy and inequality of expectations

Tags: expected-value, entropy, information-theory, probability-inequalities

Consider two distinct probability distributions $P(X)$ and $Q(Y)$---defined on the same domain---with (Shannon) entropy of $H(X)$ and $H(Y)$. I am interested to prove that
$$
H(X) \leq H(Y) \implies \sum_{x}\sum_{x'} P(x)P(x')|x-x'| \leq \sum_{y}\sum_{y'} Q(y)Q(y')|y-y'| 
$$

Any answer, comments, or directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you believe this would be true? What kind of examples have you looked at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.

Take two probability distributions with the same entropy (1 bit):

$$P(0) = \tfrac{1}{2}, \quad P(1) = 0, \quad P(1001) = \tfrac{1}{2}$$
and
$$Q(0) = \tfrac{1}{2}, \quad Q(1) = \tfrac{1}{2}, \quad Q(1001) = 0.$$

However, the sum

$$\sum_x \sum_{x'} R(x) R(x') \left|x - x'\right|$$

is $250$ and $0.25$, respectively.